# Двоеточие после "удивительнее"

Tags: двоеточие

*От этого становится ещё удивительнее, насколько большая разница.*

Нужно ли двоеточие?

Answer (score 1):

***От этого становится ещё удивительнее, насколько большая разница.***

Это сложноподчиненное предложение (СПП). В качестве связи между предложениями используется союзное слово ***насколько***, поэтому ставится запятая.

**Парный вариант** (с возможностью выбора) возможен в следующем примере:

Это вызывает вопрос, насколько искренни эти заявления (СПП, ставится запятая).

Это вызывает вопрос: насколько искренни эти заявления? (БСП, ставится двоеточие).

Comment: Во вопросе **насколько**, а не "настолько". Лучше просто оставить запятую. Если Вы сознательно заменили слово, лучше было упомянуть об этом, я думаю.

Comment: Спасибо, Вы очень внимательны (только вот редко заходите на форум, Вас здесь не хватает). Придется сознаться в преднамеренности замены. Мне показалось, что это они ошиблись, да и сейчас я думаю, что предложение грамматически некорректно. Мне не нравится стыковка  слов "удивительнее" и "насколько", так как сложно определить вид связи между предложениями (обычно эти слова встречаются в разных конструкциях). Например: (1) тем удивительнее, что они такие разные;  (2) удивительно, насколько они разные.

Answer (score 0):

Ни в коем случае, нет никаких оснований ставить двоеточие.